# how can I implement an agnostic data layer?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns, ado.net

I am writing a proof of concept application.
When coming to the data layer we need the ability to connect to different databases and different technology might be used

Ado.net (sqlCommand etc..)
Entity Framework.
Nhibernate.

What I am saying is that the whatever calls our RepositoryService class is ignorant about the provider used.EG "Entity Framework, Raw Ado.Net NHibernate" etc..

Is there an example out there or an empty shell I can look at or a code snippet from you.
Just to give an idea how would you go about it.

Noddy implementation to give you an idea omitted possible IOC etc..:

```
 public class BusinessService
    {
        public List<CustomerDto> GetCustomers()
        {
            RepositoryService repositoryService=new RepositoryService();
            List<CustomerDto> customers = repositoryService.GetCustomers().ToList();
            return customers
        }
    }
    public class RepositoryService:IRepository
    {
        private string dbProvider;
        public RepositoryService()
        {
            //In here determine the provider from config file  EG Sql- EF etc.. and call the appriopiate repository
          //  dbProvider=???
        }
        public IEnumerable<CustomerDto> GetCustomers()
        {
             //Get the customers from the choosen repository
        }
    }
    public interface IRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<CustomerDto> GetCustomers();
    }
    public class SqlRepository : IRepository
    {
        public IEnumerable<CustomerDto> GetCustomers()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class EFRepository : IRepository
    {
        public IEnumerable<CustomerDto> GetCustomers()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class CustomerDto
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }
```

Many thanks

Comment: An abstraction over abstraction? Don't you think, that you're going to invent you own OR/M? What's the point? I mean, do you *really* need such flexibility in practice?

Comment: Dennis thanks for your time.I am looking for suggestions not criticism.If you were given the task to write a class that could fetch data using different orms or raw ado.net how would you do it? Nothing is set in stone here i need to give you something to go on.Sometimes managers make decisions not devs.If It was me I would go for one and that is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be more clear about your objectives (and those of your manager). Accessing your data thrue some repository interfaces is a first step. The second step is to have a shared object representation of your data table rows (or your entities if you want to refine table mappings).

The idea behind the scene may be: 
a) We don't know ORM technologies well and want to try without taking the risk to have poor performances. 
b) Our database is very huge and we manipulate huges amounts of data.
c) Our database contains many thousands of tables.
d) ...

The general answer may be :
1) use the choosen ORM when possible.
2) downgrade to ADO.NET or even to stored procedures when performances are poor.

Entity Framework and NHibernate use an high level entity mapping abstraction. Do you want to use this? If not, you may use lightweight object mappers like Dapper or PetaPoco.

ORM are a good way to lower the development costs of 70% to 80% the database access code (95% if you just read data). Choosing to be able to use all of them will ensure you that the potential cost gains will be lost.

PetaPoco is very interesting for a first experiment because it includes the very light mapper source code in your C# project and generates table objects with an easy to understand T4 transform file (all the source code is small and included in your data access layer). Its major default is that its author does have time to work on it last years.

If ORM technologies can make program easier to write and scale, they have drawbacks:

1) because you work outside the database, operation between in memory (or not yet persisted) objects and database data can easily become very costly : if a search for data concerning one object in database generate one request, an operation on a collection of objects will generate as many requests as there are items in the collection.

2) because of the complex change tracking mechanisms in high level ORM, saving data can become very slow if you don't take care of this.

3) The more the ORM offers functionalities, the more your learning curve is long.

Comment: Thank you for your time to reply.It's a times difficult to ask a question because if you make the question to long and detailed there is a good chance people will not read it!!! The aim of this exercise was to build something flexible as not all teams in our company uses the same data access technology.This was a well definied exercise because the instruction given to me were poor .Kind of "get on with it.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I generally accomplish this task is to have different concrete implementations of your repository interfaces, so you can have an EFRepository or an NHibernateRepository or an AdoNetRepository or an InMemoryDatabaseRepository implementation.

As long as you encapsulate the construction of your repository (through a factory or dependency injection or whatever) the types that are consuming your repository don't have to be know exactly what kind of repository that they are working with.